# How do I find a non child View in Android?

Tags: android, view

I have a TextView inside the same RelativeLayout as a chunk of ImageView derived custom classes. I'd like to be able to write to the TextView from inside these other Views. How do I do this since I am unable to use findViewById due to it not being a child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to be able to write to the
>   TextView from inside these other
>   Views.

That is not a good design. `Views` should not interact with other random `Views`. Communication between those should be handled by the `Activity`, or possibly by making the `RelativeLayout` be a custom `View` and having it mediate the communication.

Comment: Well the Activity currently has a method for logging into the TextView. Can I call that somehow?

Comment: @Zulaxia: I have no idea what "logging into the TextView" means. Your activity should register some sort of listener to the ImageView(s). Your ImageViews should notify that listener when events occur. The activity should take action upon those events, such as updating the TextView.

Comment: Sorry, that read as complete rubbish. Was on my phone and predictive text butchered it without me noticing.

Thanks for the reply, seems obvious now that you mention listeners. Thanks for pointing me back in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findViewById` of current **`Activity`** to find those other Views.

```
public class CustomView extends View {
    private Activity activity;

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        activity = (Activity) context;
    }

    private View findOtherView(int id) {
        return activity.findViewById(id);
    }
}
```